# APScheduler job still runs once it added to scheduler when exceeding the max_worker number

Tags: python, python-2.7, job-scheduling, apscheduler

I had a script that periodically logged on a certain linux server using ssh and the maximum connection number of the server is 13, so I set parameter `max_workers` 10. But I found when scheduling jobs in background, it failed to connect to the linux server because of exceeding the ssh maximum connection number. I have no idea why it happened since I have limited the `max_worker`. The code simplified as below:

```
import paramiko
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from paramiko import SSHClient

class SSH(object):  
    def __init__(self):
        self.scheduler = BackgroundScheduler({'apscheduler.executors.default': {'class': 'apscheduler.executors.pool:ThreadPoolExecutor', 'max_workers': '10'}})
    def func(self, src='127.0.0.1', user='user', password='password'):
        ssh = SSHClient()
        ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        try:
            ssh.connect(src, 22, user, password, timeout=3)
        except Exception as e:
            print 'Failed to connect to %s' % src
            sys.exit(1)

    def schedule(self, arg):
        for i in range(100):
            self.scheduler.add_job(self.func, 'interval',
                               seconds=60),
                               misfire_grace_time=100000000000,
                               kwargs=dict(
                                   src=arg['source'],
                                   user=arg['username'],
                                   password=arg['password'],

                               ))
            try:
                if not self.scheduler.running:
                    self.scheduler.start()
            except Exception as e:
                print e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ssh_client = SSH()
    ssh_client.schedule(arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you enable debug logging (initialize the logging module on the DEBUG level) to see what is happening. Most likely the job does finish but the connection is left open for some reason. Alternatively make the function print something when it exits.